Calculating bilateral distances across a large dataframe (>1 mil rows) of longitude and latitude
Hi i've attempted this with pandas by creating a distance matrix of all the 1 mil locations (so a symmetric matrix of 1 million by 1 million) needless to say it does not work as it is too big for pandas :(
Trying to find an alternative to this. Have tried dask and Vaex but am struggling. Can i get some help please? WHat would you use if you had to create a distance matrix to calculate pairwise distances between > 1 mill of locations
Ideally a distance matrix of pairwise distances

First of all: you need to include a minimal reproduceable example of what you've tried.  Second, are there some constraints that prevent you from "just" brute-force iterating over the positions and calculating the results w/o a library (ie. must run in under X minutes, or must fit in Y Mb of memory)?

So you are proposing to generate and store a matrix with a Trillion float values! Even if feasible what are you then going to do since you clearly cannot inspect them all. Whatever the end use is then you should focus on achieving this without the unrealistic plan to first generate all the numbers.

Since calculating like half a trillion distances is not really a use case, I suspect this to be an X Y problem.
